# Ubuntu Canonical partners

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, software-sources, canonical

### Issue:

- Open Software & Updates and check "Canonical-supported free and open-source software (main)"
- Open Software Updater, gives me an error "Not all updates can be installed" and offers a partial upgrade
- Uncheck the box and reopen Updater without error

### Attempts:

- Commenting or removing the repository from /etc/apt/sources.list entirely (checkbox is unaffected)

  - `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner`
- Checking `apt update` - all packages up to date
- Probably useless but also,

  - `apt -f install`
  - `dpkg --reconfigure -a`
  - `apt clean && apt autoclean`

Could my sources.list be considered  corrupted by the updater? I've removed a few comments and it could be using those to locate the APT line, but it seems a bit precarious.

I should also mention, I recently did the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: Always avoid "partial" upgrades as they're typically a symptom of something wrong with your software sources. Check that first then do `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: @ChanganAuto warning is gone (amazing) but apt update still won't hit the canonical repo whether Canonical is checked or unchecked. I can always add it manually but that'd defeat the purpose of the box. What is the box actually supposed to do?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I should mention, I moved from Canada to Main server and it changes my sources.list accordingly for ubuntu repos.